# Write a method buildTree() in Python to form a Binary Tree from a parent array

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I can construct a Binary Tree in level order when I have a parent array, but I can't figure out how to construct it when we have 'N' in the array, representing Null.

For example, if the parent array is [3, 9, 20, N, N, 15, 7], the tree is:

[Click to view the Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1iW7.png)

I have the C++ code for the same, but I'm unable to figure out the Python code.
The C++ code is as follows:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;

    Node(int val) {
        data = val;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
}; 

Node* buildTree(string str)
{   
    // Corner Case
    if(str.length() == 0 || str[0] == 'N')
            return NULL;
    
    // Creating vector of strings from input 
    // string after spliting by space
    vector<string> ip;
    
    istringstream iss(str);
    for(string str; iss >> str; )
        ip.push_back(str);
        
    // Create the root of the tree
    Node *root = new Node(stoi(ip[0]));
        
    // Push the root to the queue
    queue<Node*> queue;
    queue.push(root);
        
    // Starting from the second element
    int i = 1;
    while(!queue.empty() && i < ip.size()) {
            
        // Get and remove the front of the queue
        Node* currNode = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
            
        // Get the current node's value from the string
        string currVal = ip[i];
            
        // If the left child is not null
        if(currVal != "N") {

            // Create the left child for the current Node
            currNode->left = new Node(stoi(currVal));
                
            // Push it to the queue
            queue.push(currNode->left);
        }
            
        // For the right child
        i++;
        if(i >= ip.size())
            break;
        currVal = ip[i];
            
        // If the right child is not null
        if(currVal != "N") {
                
            // Create the right child for the current node
            currNode->right = new Node(stoi(currVal));
                
            // Push it to the queue
            queue.push(currNode->right);
        }
        i++;
```

}

```
return root;
```

}

Comment: Did you try to write the method `buildTree()` in Python, any [example] you have? Or any concrete issue you are struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you could use this function:

```
def buildTree(lst):
    def grab(it, nextlevel):
        value = next(it, "N")
        if value != "N":
            node = Node(value)
            nextlevel.append(node)
            return node

    # Create the root of the tree
    it = iter(lst)
    nextlevel = []
    root = grab(it, nextlevel)

    while nextlevel:
        level = nextlevel
        nextlevel = []
        for node in level:
            node.left = grab(it, nextlevel)
            node.right = grab(it, nextlevel)

    return root
```

Example call:

```
lst = [3, 9, 20, "N", "N", 15, 7]
root = buildTree(lst)
```